# How to prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{ \frac{a}{x^n} - 1}$ converges when $a \neq 0$ and $|x| < 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to prove that the sum of infinite series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{ \frac{a}{x^n} - 1}$$
converges when $a \neq 0$ and $|x| < 1$?

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: $|a-x^{n}|\geq \frac {|a|} 2$ for $n$ sufficiently large.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  Thank you very much. So, if I understand correctly, this infinite sum can be upper bounded for sufficiently large $n$ as, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{a - x^n} \leq \frac{|a|}{2(1-x)}$, correct?  Is there any known proof for this $|a-x^n| \geq \frac{|a|}{2}$ ?